# How can I support multiple stylus input for UWP InkCanvas?

Tags: c#, uwp

I am developing a drawing program in UWP and would like for my program to support multiple stylus input. When I developed in WPF, I was able to get multiple stylus input from WPF's version of InkCanvas after doing some clever mouse and stylus event handling. However, for UWP's version of InkCanvas, my program seems to only allow for one stylus input at a time. However, when I use Microsoft's built-in applications such as Whiteboard, it can clearly support multiple stylus input at once.

My question therefore is can UWP natively support multiple stylus input? And if so, would I be able to do it through UWP's InkCanvas, or would I need to do it some other way? I can say with full confidence that our hardware definitely supports multiple stylus input.

Answer (score 2):

You need to enable custom drying then set the property that allows multiple user input.

`InkCanvas.InkPresenter.ActivateCustomDrying();`

`InkCanvas.InkPresenter.SetPredefinedConfiguration(InkPresenterPredefinedConfiguration.SimpleMultiplePointer);`